# Bash read line buffer overflow

Tags: bash, buffer-overflow, tee

I have a bash script that reads lines from a file and then does some logic with those lines.

So

```
while read line;
do
# some stuff
done < "$1"
```

In the body of the while loop I am piping the output of one command to `tee`.
When this output is very large, on the order of 100K, the next call to read line fails and the while loop terminates before all lines in the file are read.

Why does this happen? I am not a bash expert, but it seems like some sort of buffer overflow is happening. If so, how do I correct this?

Thanks,
-D

Edit :
So some clarification is in order. $1 is the first command line argument given to the bash script, which corrisponds to a filename. What I am exactly doing is giving each line of the input file as a parameter to another program. I am piping the stdout and stderr of that program to `| tee -a somefile`

The program I am giving the input to is non-standard. Depending on the line of the file I am reading the output of this program could be very large.

So a more verbose example of what I am doing is

```
while read line;
do
setSomeVar1
setSomeVar2
program --output="$setSomeVar1" -options "$line" 2>&1 | tee -a "$setSomeVar2"
done < "$1"
```

Thanks,

-D

Comment: What is `$1`? What exactly are you doing in the body of the loop?

Comment: Right tool for the job... bash ain't it.

Comment: It's possible that something else in the loop body is reading from standard input as well, which means it is siphoning off data from the file which is intended for the `read` command.

Comment: If comands use stdio and are connected to a terminal they'll be flushed per line. Else, read about  stdbuf [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)

Comment: @chepner it is the first command line argument, in this case a filename. The loop gives each line of a file as an argument to another program.

Comment: @n.m. What do you mean? Doing a loop in bash isn't the right tool for what job? I didn't go into what job I was doing, I am merely asking why this bash while loop doesn't work, given certain conditions.

Comment: @chepner As I a said above, I am no bash expert, but does `| someCommand` count as sending from stdin? Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK i misread the problem, I thought you are reading 100K lines with bash,

Comment: If you don't post exactly what you are doing, we can't guess what is wrong. Post the code that you are working with.

Answer (score 3):

If anything else in the body of the loop is reading from standard input, you can have `read` get its input from a different file descriptor (3 is usually free):

```
while read -u 3 line; do
...
done 3< "$1"
```

Comment: a guess as good as any considering the lack of details (good guess though!)

Comment: @Fredrik I didn't mean to give a lack of details. I had thought I had given all the relevant ones. I updated the above post with additional details. Are there any other details that would be helpful?

Comment: Alas this did not resolve the issue. It is still terminating the script after large output.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue myself, if anyone's still looking at this after all these years.

In the `# do some stuff` block, whatever commands you're running in there that might be siphoning stdin for some reason, add a `< /dev/null` so that you explicitly make that command take in no stdin. This worked for me.